# Изменить местоположение Validator-а

Tags: php, html, jquery

Есть форма входа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы красный текст(текст ошибки) был внутри черной фигуры, который расположен под полем справа(вместо надписи "Нужен для входа в кабинет") ?

Answer (score 1):

одно из решений это атрибут required:

```
$("input").prop('required',true);
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/d6ae4268/)

можно воспользоваться разными плагинами, например [этим](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/)